# How to launch Settings inbuilt App from our App?

Tags: iphone

i want to open inbuilt Setting Application in my Application ..
i want some idea to perform it.. how could i make it??

with some code..should be more effecient.
Thanks.
Keyur Prajapati

Comment: refer this : http://www.inappsettingskit.com/

Comment: i haved try it for [UIApplication sharedApplication] , but i coudn't found the right steps to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in iOS 8:

```
if (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL) {
        NSURL *settings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:settings];
    }
```